How to create custom typed response with error code?
enum ErrorCode {
  OK = "OK",
  MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED = "MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED",
  UNKNOWN_ERROR = "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
}

type Response = {
  code: ErrorCode;
  message: string;
  data?: any;
};

type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

type MaximumExceeded = {
  limit: number;
  inclusive: boolean;
};

export async function api(id: string, maximum: number) {
  try {
    if (maximum > 10) {
      return {
        code: ErrorCode.MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED,
        message: "maximum exceeded",
        data: {
          limit: 10,
          inclusive: false,
        },
      };
    }

    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve([
          {
            name: "Alice",
            age: 30,
          },
          {
            name: "Bob",
            age: 31,
          },
        ]);
      }, 1000);
    });

    return {
      code: ErrorCode.OK,
      message: "success",
      data: result,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
      return {
        code: ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR,
        message: e.message,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        code: ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR,
        message: "Unknown error",
      };
    }
  }
}

async function test() {
  const result = await api("123", 20);
  if (result.code === ErrorCode.OK) {
    console.log(result.data?.name);
  } else if (result.code == ErrorCode.MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED) {
    console.log("limit", result.data?.limit);
  } else {
    console.log(result.message);
  }
}

I have some predefined error codes.
The result of the api function follows the same pattern, it alway has a code for program, a message for human and a optional data field. The promise inside is some external resources out of controll.
What I want to do is that I want to caller to get the right type by asserting on the error code. Thanks a lot.

You should look into Discriminated Unions, sometimes also called Tagged Unions
enum ErrorCode {
  OK = "OK",
  MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED = "MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED",
  UNKNOWN_ERROR = "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
}

interface Response<Code, Data> {
  code: Code;
  message: string;
  data: Data;
}

type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

type MaximumExceeded = {
  limit: number;
  inclusive: boolean;
};

type GetUserResponse =
  | Response<ErrorCode.OK, Person>
  | Response<ErrorCode.MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED, MaximumExceeded>
  | Response<ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR, unknown>;

function example(response: GetUserResponse) {
  if (response.status === ErrorCode.OK) {
    // response.data is Person
    console.log(response.data.name);
  } else if (response.status === ErrorCode.MAXIMUM_EXCEEDED) {
    // response.data is MaximumExceeded
    console.log(response.data.limit);
  }
}

What this does is that, when you check for a status, typescript is able to narrow down the type of response.data within that if() block

If there are dozens of ErrorCode, is listing all of them in the union type the best we can do here?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Evilolipop if they all have different responses, and you want to distinguish between all them, I'd say yes. Otherwise you can do something like type GetUserReponse = (...) & Response<ErrorCode, unknown> to handle the cases you don't care about the shape of the response, or something like Response<ErrorCode.FOO | ErrorCode.BAR, FooBarData> if multiple codes have the same shape of response
